# Compiz crashes with in 13.04 when plugging a second monitor in

Tags: compiz, 13.04, multiple-monitors

Since I have updated to Ubuntu 13.04, every time when I plug in a second monitor compiz crashes.

Sometimes, when my computer has a high CPU Value, compiz also crashes.
When Compiz crashes, the launcher-bar and the menu and frames of the windows are missing and I have to restart my computer.

I think the problem could be the graphic card:
I have a **HP Probook 4720s**. When I run `lspci`, the following line shows my grapic card:

```
`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4350/4550]`
```

If you need more information, tell me how to gather the needed information and i will post it.

Thanks for your help,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, don't reboot, just start "compiz config manager" and toggle checkbox on "Window decoration".  It is still annoying, but will do the job for now.